# Linking file systems with removable media

Tags: linux, filesystems, symlink, chrome-book, removable-storage

Is there a way to create a link between something like `/usr/bin` and `/removable/SD Card/usr/bin`?

I have a chromebook with crouton installed and a 128GB SD Card. I would like to be able to store some of the bigger programs and scripts on the SD Card, but not the entire file system.

Is there a way to create a link so if I try to do something like `$ pycharm` it looks for the binary in both `/usr/bin` and `/removable/SD Card/usr/bin`?

Answer (score 1):

**Add it to Your Path**

- Like other users have said, add `/removable/SD\ Card/usr/bin` to your path. The best place to put this would probably be in a file such as `sdcard.sh` in `/etc/profile.d/` (distro-dependant, not sure about Chromebooks) for the whole system, or in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` for just your user.
  This is probably the best way, just add `PATH="${PATH}:/removable/SD\ Card/usr/bin"` to your file.

**Make a Symbolic Link (a.k.a. Symlink or Soft Link)**

- You could link the files in `/removable/SD\ Card/usr/bin/` to `/usr/local/bin/`. Maybe not the best solution as you would have to add links for new files and remove old ones.

Whichever way you choose, you will need to have automounting setup so you can access the directory (unless you mount it manually every time). On ChromiumOS this is probably already setup.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `/removable/SD Card/usr/bin` to your `PATH`.

In most cases you'd want to include it in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.env`, but you can put it in your user's `.bashrc` or directly in the command line as `PATH=$PATH:'/removable/SD Card/usr/bin'`.

Note that you would avoid lots of complications if you removed space in the directory name though.